# Linux gdb 'examine' behavior

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I'm using gdb to explore a core file on Linux and I noticed weird behavior when examining memory addresses:

```
(gdb) x/f 0xbd091a10
0xbd091a10:     0
(gdb) x/g 0xbd091a10
0xbd091a10:     65574
(gdb) x/f 0xbd091a10
0xbd091a10:     65574
```

These statements were run directly back to back, and I don't understand why examining as float returns inconsistent results. The value 65574 does make sense as it corresponds to the identity of the last loaded item by the process.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Version details:

`Linux mx534vm 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:17:51 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-32.el5)`

Comment: There is no inconsistency in this. 'f' and 'g' are specifiers in different categories, 'f' for format and 'g' for unit size. Each specifier, when used, becomes the default for its own category which holds for all subsequent uses of 'x'. Thus, your last command is equivalent to `x/fg 0xbd091a10`.

Comment: You may want to refer the related post http://stackoverflow.com/a/22871099/2724703

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, I guess `g` is still stuck in my head as a format from Solaris' `dbx`. Want to post an answer so that I accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inconsistency in this. 'f' and 'g' are specifiers in different categories, 'f' for format and 'g' for unit size. Each specifier, when used, becomes the default for its own category which holds for all subsequent uses of 'x'. Thus, your two last commands are both equivalent to `x/fg 0xbd091a10`.